# Pipelines Randomly Failing on Azure pipelines when using Self Hosted Microsoft Agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have been using Azure pipelines for many years. Recently I switched to using from azure Microsoft Hosted Agents to Self hosted Agent which are running in a VMSS.

Since switching, I have noticed MANY builds fail because of an error like below. This happens quite often and very randomly. The build will be successful if I rerun the build.

```
 ---> Running in 3619316996da
unexpected EOF
##[error]unexpected EOF
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Build an image
```

Has anyone had such an issue or can help enlighten me where to look. Its pretty frustrating especially since the issue seems to be random and didn't happen with Microsoft Hosted Agents.

Comment: Error is too generic. You can enable debug logging and investigate finer details. Refer this - [Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved after updating linux/Docker to the latest version